# How to bypass Interceptors if there is no file in the body with NextJS?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, multer

I'm building a mail-sending queue service using SMTP with options with or without attachments. But with NestJS, @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file')) is required to upload files, so the option to send mail without files cannot be applied. Hoping to find a solution to this problem. Thanks
This is my controller

[image: img1]

This is an error from Interceptors

[image: img2]

I tried to find the solution but still can't find it

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it by using a customer interceptor which would be using file interceptor internally, something like this:

```
import { FileInterceptor } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CustomFileInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

    if (request.files && request.files.file) {
      return new FileInterceptor('file').intercept(context, next);
    }

    return next.handle();
  }
}
```